# Always show specific result at the end of a for each loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I got a project page that echoes multiple projects in a foreach loop, and every 4 results it starts a new row on the page.

However I got an element that always needs to be shown as the last result. How can I achieve that?

My foreach loop:

```
<? 
$tel = 1;

foreach ($projectcr as $project) {
$article_images = $project['images']; // Get image parameters of the article

$pictures = json_decode($article_images); // Split the parameters apart
$introtext = $project['introtext'];
    if ($project['title'] != '') {
        if($tel == 1) {
            echo '<div class="row">';   
        }
        echo '
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 js-wpg-item" data-categories="gardening">
            <a class="card  portfolio-grid__card js-wpg-card" href="project/'.$project['alias'].'.html">
                <img src="cms/'.$pictures->{'image_intro'}.'" class="card-img-top portfolio-grid__card-img wp-post-image" alt="19" height="240" width="360">
                <div class="card-block portfolio-grid__card-block">
                    <h5>'.$project['title'].'</h5>
                    <p>'.$project['created'].'</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>'
            ;

        if(($tel % 4) == 0){
            echo '</div> <div class="row">'; 
        }
        $tel++; 
    }
} 
if(($tel % 4) != 0){
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

The element I want to be shown as last block:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 js-wpg-item" data-categories="">
        <div class="portfolio-grid__card portfolio-grid__card--dummy js-wpg-card" href="projects/">
            <div class="portfolio-grid__card-block text-center">
                <span class="fa fa-cloud-upload fa-2x"></span>
                <h5>Uw volgende project hier?</h5>
                <p class="portfolio-grid__card-text">
                    <a href="contact.php" class="btn btn-primary">NEEM CONTACT OP</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.col -->

</div><!-- /.row -->
```

This has the following result:

[image]

The element is now shown outside the row, while I need it to be inside the row (but only the last one).

Comment: did you know that you can write the HTML as a first class language combined with PHP? It makes it much easier to read and edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last `if condition` just after ending `foreach`

```
if(($tel % 4) != 0){
    //echo div.col-... inside .row started in loop
    echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">always to be shown at last</div>';
    //end .row
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve that but can't you just add a element to your array?

```
$p = [];
$p['title'] = 'Uw volgende project hier?';
$p['created'] = '<a href="contact.php" class="btn btn-primary">NEEM CONTACT OP</a>'

array_push($projectcr, $p);
```

A other way to do it is to check if its the last element in the array

```
$lastElement = end($array);
// you code 
    if($project == $lastElement){
        //add the static block
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the content you want to show at the end of the loop. Don't check the condition and add the closing tag for row div, because it will fail to add the close tag if modulus of `$tel` is equal to zero. Your last content should be shown in new row but it will not close the tag.

```
$last = <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 js-wpg-item" data-categories="">
    <div class="portfolio-grid__card portfolio-grid__card--dummy js-wpg-card" href="projects/">
        <div class="portfolio-grid__card-block text-center">
            <span class="fa fa-cloud-upload fa-2x"></span>
            <h5>Uw volgende project hier?</h5>
            <p class="portfolio-grid__card-text">
                <a href="contact.php" class="btn btn-primary">NEEM CONTACT OP</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

foreach($projectcr as $project) {
...//your code
...
}

echo $last. '</div>';
```